# Force NSTabView to load new instance of a tab on MacOS

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstabview

In an `NSTabViewController` with a number of tabs, I didn't realize that by default when a tab is chosen, you are not given a new instance of the view. Is there a way to force a new instance of a view to be loaded all the time?

Comment: Why do you use a tab view? Does the user expect to see the same view again when switching tabs? Why do you want to replace the view?

Comment: No the user does not expect to see the same view again. So is it possible to get a new instance of the view when switching between them. If yes, information on how to do it would be appreciated.

Comment: Can't you switch views without a tab view?

Comment: In the application that I am developing the NSTabController with a toolbar type tab provides a particularly attractive UI for the interface. However the nature of the app requires that the views shown in the tabs be new views and not restored previous views. Until I know whether or not it is possible to do this with a tabbed controller, I am not looking for alternatives. I just want to know if this is possible and if so how to implement it.

Comment: Hack: Set the default tabView to an infrequent item in IB; then the app chooses a default - being different, will get a new one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ignoring *why* you would want to do this, you should be able to replace the view for a tab before that tab is displayed by

- creating an object that conforms to `<NSTabViewDelegate>`
- connecting it to the tab view's `delegate` outlet
- implementing the `-(void)tabView:(NSTabView *)tabView willSelectTabViewItem:(NSTabViewItem *)tabViewItem` method

Comment: this works. However I am encountering a problem with storyboards.